# IBM Watson Alchemy service in Spanish

Tags: ibm-watson

Using the IBM Alchemy service from [demo link](https://alchemy-language-demo.mybluemix.net/) I found that when I say in Spanish "Me nombre es Gustavo" give me back `There has been the following error: 400 - Bad Request`

Does Alchemy service not support Spanish?

[image: IBM Alchemy service Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This demo is using a model that was trained for English, but it actually hits a dozen or so API endpoints and most of them do support Spanish. (The `emotion` API apparently does not - it returns "unsupported-text-language" and causes the error you see reported.)

If you scroll down a bit, you can see the output from the different endpoints. Try Taxonomy, for example:

[image: IBM Watson Alchemy API Taxonomy for Spanish text]

Note that the model it's using is trained for English websites and news content. So, it's doing it's best but you'll receive much better results with a custom model. See http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/alchemylanguage/customizing.shtml for more info.

Comment: thank you, i will create my own name extractor, because for the watson knowledge studio it costs too much :o